# can you deploy cruise control .net as a web service/web app?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm investigating the possibility of utilizing my web host as a cruise control.net build server. If I have access to MsBuild or can deploy msBuild and run it, it would be great. I can not however find any resources that would tell me if cruise control supports being run as a web service or web app.

Is this type of deployment possible? If not could the UI (it's web-based I believe) control section sit on the web server and send requests to the actual build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This was very doable, just copying the web directory from Cc.net's install and editing a few config files.

Comment: I want to do the same thing (host is on my GoDaddy account). Can you share your notes?

Answer (score 1):

CruiseControl requires it's own Windows service running in the background. Unless you can install *services* (not web services, but actual Windows services) on your host (which is unlikely unless you have a dedicated server), or just keep the EXE running until the end of time in debug mode, you won't be able to use CC.Net in this way.

It's better to keep this as part of your dev environment, anyway. You don't want the security risk involved with having that level of control available to anyone that manages to log in to the server.

Comment: so the dashboard itself is inadvisable to park on my web host?

Comment: The dashboard needs to be able to connect to the service, so what would be the point? You'll need access to both machines for the dashboard to be of any use, so why go through the trouble of splitting the install? Also, I'm not sure of an easy way to configure CC to talk to a different machine from where the site is hosted, though I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: I've set this up already, where my dashboard reaches to the server, and the server handles builds, so that effectively even without being able to reach the server, if I can reach the dashboard, I can manipulate it. The next step is finding a simple way to lock down the dashboard to asp.net forms login access. The dashboard can be used to tell the server to push up a new build to the server the dashboard sits on.

Comment: What's the benefit of having your deployment system sitting on the server?

Comment: I can trigger deployments remotely, where... the debug pipeline has fixes that I have not pushed to production yet. After I've vetted the debug pipeline well enough, I can remotely invoke a promotion of the debug code. Additionally someone else on the team that does not have production server administration capability can remotely trigger builds on the build server that they also don't have administration access to.